# Word count in Rails?

Tags: ruby, word-count

Say I have a blog model with Title and Body. How I do show the number of words in Body and characters in Title? I want the output to be something like this

Title: Lorem
Body: Lorem Lorem Lorem

This post has word count of 3.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
"Lorem Lorem Lorem".scan(/\w+/).size
=> 3
```

**UPDATE**: if you need to match rock-and-roll as one word, you could do like

```
"Lorem Lorem Lorem rock-and-roll".scan(/[\w-]+/).size
=> 4
```

Comment: What about "add some rock-n-roll"? There are three words here while your variant will find five.

Comment: One thing I noticed is this method will count apostrophes so it's becomes two words. I couldn't figure out how to modify it so I just did a gsub before this to remove all apostrophes.

Answer (score 20):

Also:

```
"Lorem Lorem Lorem".split.size
=> 3
```

Comment: I've experienced this method to be a lot more reliable, the /[\w-]+/ regex doesn't seem very reliable.

Comment: I like this a lot more. Simple. I added `squish` before the `split`.

Answer (score 5):

If you're interested in performance, I wrote a quick benchmark:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'bigdecimal/math'
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/filters'

# Where "shakespeare" is the full text of The Complete Works of William Shakespeare...

puts 'Benchmarking shakespeare.scan(/\w+/).size x50'
puts Benchmark.measure { 50.times { shakespeare.scan(/\w+/).size } }
puts 'Benchmarking shakespeare.squish.scan(/\w+/).size x50'
puts Benchmark.measure { 50.times { shakespeare.squish.scan(/\w+/).size } }
puts 'Benchmarking shakespeare.split.size x50'
puts Benchmark.measure { 50.times { shakespeare.split.size } }
puts 'Benchmarking shakespeare.squish.split.size x50'
puts Benchmark.measure { 50.times { shakespeare.squish.split.size } }
```

The results:

```
Benchmarking shakespeare.scan(/\w+/).size x50
 13.980000   0.240000  14.220000 ( 14.234612)
Benchmarking shakespeare.squish.scan(/\w+/).size x50
 40.850000   0.270000  41.120000 ( 41.109643)
Benchmarking shakespeare.split.size x50
  5.820000   0.210000   6.030000 (  6.028998)
Benchmarking shakespeare.squish.split.size x50
 31.000000   0.260000  31.260000 ( 31.268706)
```

In other words, `squish` is slow with Very Large Strings™. Other than that, `split` is faster (twice as fast if you're not using `squish`).

Answer (score 3):

The answers here have a couple of issues:

1. They don't account for utf and unicode chars (diacritics): áâãêü etc...
2. They don't account for apostrophes and hyphens. So `Joe's` will be considered two words `Joe` and `'s` which is obviously incorrect. As will `twenty-two`, which is a single compound word.

Something like this works better and account for those issues:

```
foo.scan(/[\p{Alpha}\-']+/)
```

You might want to look at my **[Words Counted](https://github.com/abitdodgy/words_counted)** gem. It allows to count words, their occurrences, lengths, and a couple of other things. It's also very well documented.

```
counter = WordsCounted::Counter.new(post.body)
counter.word_count #=> 3
counter.most_occuring_words #=> [["lorem", 3]]
# This also takes into capitalisation into account.
# So `Hello` and `hello` are counted as the same word.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
"caçapão adipisicing elit".scan(/[\w-]+/).size 
=> 5
```

But as we can see, the sentence has only 3 words. The problem is related with the accented characters, because the regex \w doesn't consider them as a word character [A-Za-z0-9_].

An improved solution would be

```
I18n.transliterate("caçapão adipisicing elit").scan(/[\w-]+/).size
=> 3
```

Comment: I ran into the same issue with a French string and used `"caçapão adipisicing elit".scan(/[[:alpha:]]+/).size` which also works.

Comment: But what about the French word *grand-mère*? `"grand-mère".scan(/[[:alpha:]]+/).size #=> 2`, but `I18n.transliterate("grand-mère").scan(/[\w-]+/).size #=> 1`.

Answer (score 2):

```
"Lorem Lorem Lorem".scan(/\S+/).size
=> 3
```