# Is it better to store large word count as a column in a database or it would be an overkill?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got the following from this question: [Word count in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107621/word-count-in-rails)

`content.scan(/[\w-]+/).size`

the `posts` `content` attribute will be large (between 3000~4000 words). Should I use a virtual attribute or create a column in the database? (I'm not sure which one is easier and better for performance).

Answer (score 1):

I think having a separate column for word count will boost your application performance. But its not a good database design. How ever I look it it in the following order

1. Business (client business is the first)
2. App (our app should allow client to streamline his business, not
   to change the business according to our app)
3. DB is just a helper module to keep the data (there is no doubt
   that DB should be designed, :))

Answer (score 1):

I suggest going with virtual attribute. It is nothing wrong to store this value in the database, probably it makes sense, but one important thing is that "premature optimization is the root of all evil". Make your piece of software work correct, and optimize later, when it is needed. 
In blog-like application (which I guess you are doing) probably it is better to cache entire html page, or page fragments, when you encounter performance problems.